# adjust ggplot2 geom tile height and width

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to shrink the height and width of my geom_tile.

I realized my question is similar to 
[How to adjust the tile height in geom tile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655710/how-to-adjust-the-tile-height-in-geom-tile), but my y values are strings instead of coordinates so I am not sure how to adjust my y values based on height.

I shrink height and width by 0.5 but it creates "grey spaces" between the tiles. Is there any way to remove the "grey spaces" so that the tiles are adjacent to each other?

```
# data frame
fd=data.frame(x = rep(c("x","y","z"),3), 
              y=c("a","b","c","b","c","a","c","a","b"),
              z=c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1))

# plot
(p <- ggplot(fd, aes(x, y, height=.5, width=.5)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) 
 + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue", limits=c(0,1)) 
 + theme_grey() 
 + labs(x = "", y= "") 
 + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) 
 + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) 
 + theme(legend.position = "none", axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, angle=90, hjust=0, colour="black")))
```

[image: Fig.1]

Comment: 'Is there any way to remove the "grey spaces" so that the tiles are adjacent to each other?' -- isn't that the default output when you don't set height and width to 0.5?

Comment: Also, minor comment, when you set something to a fixed number rather than mapping it to a column in your data (like you do with `height` and `width`), it's best to *not* put it inside `aes()`.

Comment: If you just want to control the aspect ratio of the tiles, you can do that when you output the graph. First, remove the width and height arguments, then (for example) compare `pdf("graph1.pdf", 5,10); p; dev.off()` with `pdf("graph2.pdf", 10,5); p; dev.off()`.

Comment: @eipi10 `+ coord_fixed(ratio=1)` should also keep a `1:1` ratio.

Comment: yes. that's the default output without the height, width. however, if i want to change the aspect ratio of the tiles inside aes I'm left with the "grey spaces". It sounds like as epi10 said, the best way is to change the aspect ratio of tiles when i'm outputting the graph.

Comment: or @aMrFlick pointed out, coord_fixed(ratio=1) works too. This is neat!

Comment: Or use @MrFlick's suggestion to add `+ coord_fixed(ratio = n)` where `n` is whatever aspect ratio you want for the tiles. This is the best way, as it will maintain the aspect ratio of the tiles, regardless of the aspect ratio of the PDF "page" output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443499/how-to-fix-adjust-the-width-of-each-band-in-ggplot-geom-tile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the `aes(..., width=.5, height=.5)`

```
(p <- ggplot(fd, aes(x, y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) 
 + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue", limits=c(0,1)) 
 + theme_grey() 
 + labs(x = "", y= "") 
 + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) 
 + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) 
 + coord_fixed(ratio=1)
 + theme(legend.position = "none", 
axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, angle=90, hjust=0, colour="black")))
```

[image]