# How to control aspect ratio with both continuous and discrete axes with geom_tile in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, aspect-ratio

I want to produce a plot with `ggplot2` and `geom_tile()`. I want the tiles to have same height and width, which seems to work fine if both x and y axis are discrete (as was discussed here: [adjust ggplot2 geom tile height and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897175/adjust-ggplot2-geom-tile-height-and-width)).

If I have values on the x axis that are interpreted as continuous, however, I either get a lot of grey space in the plot and no aspect ratio of 1 when I use a discrete scale for the x axis (MWE1), or I do get a plot without grey space with a continuous scale but still no aspect ratio of 1 (MWE2). (I would insert images but it seems it is not allowed because my reputation is not high enough.)

MWE1:

```
my <- data.frame(x=c(rep(c(0.1),3),rep(c(0.3),3),rep(c(0.5),3)),y=rep(c("frac(SP1)=0.5", "frac(SP1)=0.7", "frac(SP2)=0,3"),3),z=sample(seq(1:50),9))

p <- ggplot(my, aes(x, y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue") +
  theme_grey() +
  labs(x = "", y= "") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio=1) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

MWE2:

```
my <- data.frame(x=c(rep(c(0.1),3),rep(c(0.3),3),rep(c(0.5),3)),y=rep(c("frac(SP1)=0.5", "frac(SP1)=0.7", "frac(SP2)=0,3"),3),z=sample(seq(1:50),9))

p <- ggplot(my, aes(x, y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue") +
  theme_grey() +
  labs(x = "", y= "") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0.1,0.3,0.5),expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio=1) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Is there a way that I can still control aspect ratio when dealing with discrete and continuous scale? Or a way to tell ggplot2 to interpret the x values as discrete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I quite understand your question, but I think this is what you want:

```
p <- ggplot(my, aes(factor(x), y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue") +
  theme_grey() +
  labs(x = "", y= "") +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())

print(p)
```

I converted your `x` variable to a factor since it's not really continuous anyways. Now you get a 3x3 heatmap:

[image]