# How to fix/adjust the width of each band in ggplot geom_tile

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, width

Here is a sample data for my question:

```
sampledata <- matrix(c(1:60,1:60,rep(0:1,each=60),sample(1:3,120,replace = T)),ncol=3)
colnames(sampledata) <- c("Time","Gender","Grade")
sampledata <- data.frame(sampledata)
sampledata$Time <- factor(sampledata$Time)
sampledata$Grade <- factor(sampledata$Grade)
sampledata$Gender <- factor(sampledata$Gender)
```

I am plotting an heatmap from this sample data using `geom_tile`

```
color_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("#31a354","#2c7fb8", "#fcbfb8", "#f03b20"))(length((levels(factor(sampledata$Grade)))))
ggplot(data = sampledata) + geom_tile( aes(x = Time, y = Gender, fill = Grade))+scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("10","20","30","40","50"))+scale_fill_manual(values =color_palette,labels=c("0-1","1-2","2-3","3-4","4-5","5-6",">6"))+  theme_bw()+scale_y_discrete(labels=c("Female","Male"))
```

I got this graph:
[image]

I want to adjust the width of Male and Female separately so that I get different widths for different gender.The meaning of width is shown in the following pic:
[image]

Is it possible to do this by making changes to my current code? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the "widths" to be the same, you can use the `height` aesthetic within `geom_tile`:

```
ggplot(data = sampledata) +
    geom_tile(aes(x = Time, y = Gender, fill = Grade, height = 0.25))
```

[image: Plot 01]

If you want them to be independent, then you need to pass a vector of the same length of the `sampledata` `data.frame`, perhaps the easiest approach is to create a new variable:

```
# Assign Females a height of 0.25 and Males a height of 0.75
sampledata$myHeight = ifelse(sampledata$Gender == 0, 0.25, 0.75)
```

And then:

```
ggplot(data = sampledata) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x = Time, y = Gender, fill = Grade, height = myHeight))
```

[image: Plot 02]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have found this https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/674   I thought my question couldn't be answered. It is very good to know height is actually adjustable!

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the gaps between the "bands" after reducing height to <1 in `geom_tile()`? As I have only a couple of "bands", I find it looking weird to have either large "width" or gaps. I tried `geom_raster()`, but it didn't support height or width arguments at all.

Comment: @elarry I would recommend asking a new question. Just be sure to provide a reproducible example and the code you have tried. You could also include a link to this question stating how it is related but not the same as yours.